# C# - How does the ToolTip work?

Tags: winforms, button, text, tooltip

I was wondering how I am able to add one ToolTip control to the Form, and all the buttons get different texts? How does one object extends all the others, adding diferent things on each one? I don't know if I am being clear, If I don't, please let me know!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need a single tooltip control on the form and wants to display tooltips on all the controls ?

Comment: Are you asking how/why adding a tooltip control to a form creates properties like "Tooltip on Tooltip1" on all the other controls?

Comment: Yes @Blorgbeard that's my question! but MD.Unicorn already answered it...thanks anyways!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Extender Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171836), where you can define new properties for other components.

This is a feature of Visual Studio designer. The ToolTip control does not actually add a property to other controls, but Visual Studio knows that when you have a ToolTip (or any other component that is an [Extender Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171836)), it should add some other properties to property grid of the other controls. All this information is queried from the component that provides those properties (ToolTip). When you set the tooltip for button for example, Visual Studio calls the [`SetToolTip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.settooltip) method of the ToolTip control, to inform it of the new value for the control.

Please refer to provided links for more information.

Comment: Thanks!
Just one more question....if I call the `SetToolTip` method, since it's a Set method, shoudnt it be expected that it will erase its previous values? And by doing so it will erase the other buttons tooltips?

Comment: @mFeinstein: This is the signature of the method: `public void SetToolTip(Control control,string caption)`. As you see, You also pass to the method, the control to which you want to set the tooltip. Internally, ToolTip component keeps a dictionary of the controls and associated tooltips. Calling the method for a control, overwrites the tooltip for **that** control, but not others.

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense! Thank you a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It's actually very simple.
Lets say you have a windows form with two controls a button and a label.
Now add a tool tip from toolbox to your form named tooltip1.
Now right click on button and go to properties, scroll down until you find tooltip on tooltip1. set the text to whatever you want. Now do the same for label.
Run the program and move the cursor over both the controls. you'll see respective tool tips.

Comment: I know how to use tooltips...I was just wondering how they act in the backstage ;) how they really work see?

Comment: Sorry, realized it after posting my comment.